# Print a sequalize object (with sub dependent object)

Tags: json, node.js, sequelize.js, stringify

I run a query (let's say for a User table, and all it's corresponding UserPhone entries, that have a userId as a foreign key, such that a user has many phones).

I would like to print the result to console.

`JSON.stringify` only works to print the users, but not the user phones, although they exist in the sequelize response object

If i instead use `util.inspect` I get everything, but also a lot of noise, such as `$options` and many other properties of a sequelize object.

I'm not looking to change my query with `{raw: true}`, just looking to print the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have a case where I need to utilize the full Sequelize Instance but only want to return the `instance.dataValues`, so I iterate over the keys (recursively if necessary) to convert it into just the raw values. I didn't actually run the following code so it may contain some errors

```js
const extend = require('util')._extend;

function getDataValues(obj) {
  // create a copy of the dataValues
  const compact = extend({}, (obj && obj.dataValues) || obj);
  // loop over the keys
  Object.keys(compact).forEach(key => {
    const field = compact[key];
    // it's an Array of Models
    if (field instanceof Array) {
      compact[key] = field.map(include =>
        getDataValues(include)
      );
    }
    // it's a single Model
    if (field.dataValues) {
      compact[key] = extend({}, field.dataValues);
    }
    // otherwise it was a "string" or "int" or other simple value
  });
  // resolve the compacted dataValues
  return Promise.resolve(compact);
}

Model.findById(id, {
  include: [{
    model: Model2,
    as: "model_twos"
  }],
})
.then(model => getDataValues(model))
.then(compact => console.log(util.inspect(compact)));
```